# Time required for the waves to disappear from the water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, differential-equations

Suppose that some liquid was agitated in a container so that the height of its surface, represented by a function $z(x,y,t)$, is known at some instant $t_0$.

How to compute how long does it take until $z(x,y,t)\approx\langle z \rangle$?

My interest is in how to solve this problem and not in particular results. Which equations to use and not necessarily how to solve them. Also, in anticipation of the rigorous answer being $t\to\infty$, I clarify that my interest is in practical results.

Any reasonable or convenient assumption is welcome, e.g., $v_x(x,y,z,t_0)=v_y(x,y,z,t_0)=0$, constant density and viscosity, air effect on the liquid negligible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no viscoscity or friction the waves stay there for ever.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you. That's intuitive to me, but my interest is in more realistic problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface waves on water are dispersive, see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)), and if you start with a *small* hump that is much smaller than the depth then after Fourier transforming the initial state you can calculate the time evolution of it.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Very interesting link. Do you mean take the Fourier transform of $z(x,y,t_0)$? I such case I would get some $Z(k)$, that is, an alternative representation in the reciprocal space. Could you give me some hint on how to get the time evolution from this?

Comment: yes, take the FT of $z(x,t=0)$ representing the initial conditions, and call the result $\hat Z_0(x,\omega)$. Then multiply $\hat Z_0$ with the propagation kernel $e^\mathfrak j (\omega(k) t - kz)$, where now $\omega(k) \approx k-(ak)^3$ and take the inverse Fourier transform. For details, see https://archive.org/details/linearnonlinearw0000whit especially Chapter 11 and sections 11.2 and 11.3